# Getting Microsoft's DocFX to work in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild, docfx

- I downloaded DocFX and installed it from http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/.
- I added it to my environment path. I then downloaded the sample solution from https://github.com/docascode/docfx-seed and opened it as a website project. (This sample already contains the package docfx.msbuild)

The documentation says to build the solution and then browse the _src folder for the website. I do this and the solution builds fine:

> ------ Build started: Project: docfx-seed-master, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Validating Web Site Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/BaseClass/obj/Debug/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/BaseClass/Properties/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/BaseClass/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/CatLibrary/obj/Debug/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/CatLibrary/Properties/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/CatLibrary/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/SomeVbClass/My Project/'. Building directory
>   '/src/SampleClass1/SomeVbClass/'.
>
> Validation Complete
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

but there is no generated _src folder. If I however run docfx from the command line then I do indeed get a _src folder and I can browse the generated website.

So my integration of DocFX into VS2015 via MSBuild is somehow broken. Can anyone shed any light on how to get this working?

Comment: Exact same problem here : on the website, it says to use NuGet to install docfx.msbuild, and each time I build the project, the _src folder must be generated but I have nothing.

Comment: I don't know if it is related but the `docfx.msbuild` package is now deprecated in favour to `docfx.console`.